# How to connect to mosquitto broker installed on virtual machine hosted on azure?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, mosquitto

I have installed mosquitto broker on virtual machine at port 1883.This virtual machine is hosted on azure cloud.To gain access to this broker i have opened the ports by adding inbound rules.Still i am not able to publish to this mosquitto broker from outside network.

I have added the inbound rules by allowing port 1883 to allow access from the outside network

```
string ClientId = new Guid().ToString();
client = new MqttClient("104.211.219.200", 1883, false, null);
client.Connect(ClientId);
client.Publish("local", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message from local PC"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
```

Comment: What os type do you create the vm? And do you open the port in the VM NSG and the VM firewall inside?

Comment: My VM is in windows server.By opening port i mean i have created the inbound role inside the vm with port 1883

Comment: Do you also open the port in the windows firewall?

Comment: Yes i have opened port in firewall too

Comment: Do you sure the NSG associated with your subnet and NIC of the VM is the same one and allow the port?

Comment: how do i check this

Comment: You can go to the VM -> networking. There will show you the NSG associated with the subnet and NIC.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, per my experience, I think your mosquitto not works now is caused by not adding a NSG rule for your VM networking interface to allow the inbound requests from port 1883.

Here is my steps to install mosquitto server on my Azure Windows VM. Hope it helps.

1. On Azure portal, to create a Windows VM with Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter.
2. Enable `Just-in-time access` feature in tab `Configuration`, then to download a RDP file to access this VM.

   [image]
3. I uploaded the mosquitto server installation file (a x64 distribution, it comes from https://mosquitto.org/download/) to Windows VM, and try to install it.

   [image]
4. I got a issue about missing `VCRUNTIME140.dll`, then to install a VC++ 2015 distribution installation (it comes from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) to fix it.
5. Then, I open a command window at the mosquitto path and to run it.

   [image]
   [image]
6. Add an inbound rule into `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`. It allows the requests from port 1883 on Windows.
   [image]
7. Add an inbound rule into the NSG networking interface to allow the requests from port 1883 on Azure VNET.
   [image]
   [image]
8. I was using a MQTT desktop client `MQTT.fx` (it comes from https://www.hivemq.com/blog/seven-best-mqtt-client-tools/) to test for connecting, publishing & subscribing a test message.

   [image]
   [image]